# how to resolve TS warning of unused destructured values in a object. only rest/spread values is being used

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript

I often have to destructure JS objects and only use the rest/spread part. Typescript then shows the error of the unused variable.

For example, in the attached screenshot, you can see that while destructuring `cart`, I have a use-case where products is not being used while all other keys/members are being used.

TS warning is genuine so is there any way to resolve this warning of no unused vars.

[image]

Comment: You should be able to omit the variable name, according to [the TS destructuring documentation](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/variable-declarations.html#array-destructuring): `const { , ...rest } = cart;` If that only works for arrays, you could try a discard: `const { _, ...rest } = cart;`.

Comment: @DM that would only work for arrays as JS objects are not ordered so it would be ambiguous which property should be excluded. I'm not certain how the discard notation works but it would likely be similar to `const { products: _, ...rest }`.

Comment: That makes sense. Disabling the linter is probably the right call, then.